# Remove a phrase from a vector of strings

Tags: r, string, vector, gsub

I have a bunch of strings in a vector and I'm trying to remove the `" (dblheader)"` part of several of the strings.   Here is my vector of strings:

```
startinglineups$Teams       
[1] "Colorado Rockies"              "San Francisco Giants"          "Kansas City Royals"            "Cleveland Indians"            
[5] "Oakland A's (dblheader)"       "Baltimore Orioles (dblheader)" "Arizona Diamondbacks"          "Atlanta Braves"
```

I have tried using `sub(" (dblheader)", "", startinglineups$Teams)` and `gsub` but neither of them are seeming to do the trick.  I'm guessing there's a problem with the whitespace character in front, or the parentheses.  I thought that searching for the exact phrase would solve my problem, but I'm wrong.  I'm thinking there may be some escape sequence I need to use, or I'm just overthinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an escape sequence you could use (explained later).  However, since you are doing an exact match to a string, you could just add `fixed = TRUE` to your `sub()` call.

```
sub(" (dblheader)", "", startinglineups$Teams, fixed = TRUE)
```

This will also be faster than using a regex because it bypasses the regex engine.

Otherwise, the parentheses in a regular expression are used for grouping and capturing and therefore need to be escaped to be used literally.  So for regex use, you could have done

```
sub(" \\(dblheader\\)", "", startinglineups$Teams)
```